# How can I correctly decode CPR positions from ADS-B frames?

Tags: ads-b

I am decoding Compact Position Reporting (CPR) positions from ADS-B frames (the *airborne position* and *surface position* frames).

Most of my results give realistic longitude/latitude values, but some return things like 0,781518968485169 177,220642089844; or 1,76377118644068    -0,664306640625; or 2,12129237288136 -2,838134765625.

I have a feeling like I must be missing some kind of validation or some kind of frame type identification. Where can I find more information about the decoding process?

Comment: I think some people are unfamiliar with ADS-B and didn't realize that your question had to do with transponder signal coding.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.Se!

Comment: Do you use global decoding or local decoding?

Comment: Can you explain how you do the decoding, it is impossible to see from result what is wrong.

Comment: Are you using a specific library like Dump1090 - we are having similar issues lately

Comment: No, we were using homemade C# code to decode the frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were decoding Airborne Position frames having TypeCode `0`, `9-18` and `20-22`.
Apparently, frames with TypeCode `20-22` and possibly `0` have to be decode a different way.

(For now I think that I get enough information out of TypeCode `9-18` frames so I'll just skip the other ones.)

Comment: Type codes 20-22 have the same coding as 9-18, all are Airborne Position messages. 19 is Velocity, there is no CPR in there. 0 is a "no position message", there is basically only altitude in there. 1-4 is identity & emitter type. 5-8 is surface position & velocity. 5-8 have a slightly different position coding than 9-18,20-22.

Comment: In addition, if you see type 20-22 I'd expect there is something wrong with your receiver or decoder as these messages are really, really rare.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped '8-19' for '9-18'. We don't receive 20-22 now, but why would that mean there is something wrong.

Comment: 20-22 has very high position integrity which is not achieved with current day avionics.